# Arangodb remote replication

Tags: nosql, arangodb

I am reading about Arangodb and it is what I want to use for a new startup.   I am confused on the asynchronous replication.    Can I do asynchronous replication without having the enterprise edition?  I will likely have multiple machines receiving a read only copy for backup and maybe in different locations.   The enterprise edition talks about datacenter to datacenter replication and so I am confused.  Can I get a read only remote asynchronous replicant with the community edition?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do remote replication the way you describe using the documented methods here:
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/deploy/architecture/replication/

This is not per se an enterprise feature. The enterprise feature dc2dc just does the whole operational setup and runtime for you. Is there a specific reason, why you would like to stay clear of it? It is free for evaluation.

The evaluations T&C are here: https://www.arangodb.com/customer-agreement

Comment: I assumed enterprise edition would cost money, this is a startup and we do not have money.    If at some point this lifts off, enterprise support if nothing else would be needed.   But at first I do not have the cash.  Thank you.